# Add PNG object to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, png, rdkit

I tried to add the PNG object into a pandas dataframe, and it does not work.

**Here is the code I used:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import rdkit
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
from rdkit import DataStructs
from rdkit.Chem import PandasTools
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole

smiles_list = ['N[C@H](C(=O)O)C']
mol_list = []
for smiles in smiles_list:
    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
    mol_list.append(mol)
    img =Draw.MolsToGridImage(mol_list, molsPerRow = 4)


glycine = mol_list[0]

figure_list = []

bi = {}
fp = AllChem.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(glycine, 2, nBits = 1024, bitInfo = bi)
fp_arr = np.zeros((1,))
DataStructs.ConvertToNumpyArray(fp, fp_arr)
np.nonzero(fp_arr)
list(fp.GetOnBits())

prints = [(glycine, x, bi) for x in fp.GetOnBits()]
figure = Draw.DrawMorganBits(prints, molsPerRow = 4, legends = [str(x) for x in fp.GetOnBits()])
figure_list.append(figure)

df = pd.DataFrame({'smiles': smiles_list[0]}, index = [0])
PandasTools.AddMoleculeColumnToFrame(df,'smiles','Molecule')
df['Fragments'] = figure_list
df
```

Instead of displaying the PNG image inside.  the pandas dataframe, it shows the message

```
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RG...
```

I would expect to add the PNG object into a pandas dataframe.
I used the following configuration in the Google colab:

```
RDKit version: 2022.03.5 
 
OS: Windows 

Python version: Python 3.7.15  

I installed RDKit using :
pip install rdkit-pypi
```

Answer (score 0):

The PNG file can be displayed inline in the pandas dataframe like shown below with the help of a few helper functions.

```
from IPython.display import HTML
import base64
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image


def get_thumbnail(path):
    i = Image.open(path)
    i.thumbnail((150, 150), Image.LANCZOS)
    return i

def image_base64(im):
    if isinstance(im, str):
        im = get_thumbnail(im)
    with BytesIO() as buffer:
        im.save(buffer, 'jpeg')
        return base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue()).decode()

def image_formatter(im):
    return f'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{image_base64(im)}">'
```

---

And finally the code below returns the dataframe with the image.

```
HTML(df.to_html(formatters={'Fragments': image_formatter}, escape=False))
```

[image]